# How to update information in another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in database as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

There are some common columns values present in tbCompanyAgent as that of in tbLicence like LicenseNumber, LicenseIssueDate and LicenseExpirationDate. After some complex sql querires and business requirement, the columns StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate and the columns LicenceNumber, DateIssued and ExpirationDate in tbLicence are merged to a single column LicenseNumber, LicenseIssueDate and LicenseExpirationDate in tbCompanyAgent.

Also values in StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate are same for same group of records identified by Group Id Column LicenceType.

Actually there is one resident entry for all the licences which are stored in StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate columns and are identified by Resident column with 1 value.

Non Resident Licences are stored in LicenceNumber, DateIssued and ExpirationDate with 0 value.

My Question is if user try to make some updation in tbLicence that should be reflected on tbCompanyAgent. For this I have written procedure like below lines of code.

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[prCompanyAgentUpdate]
 (
 @NewLicenceNumber nvarchar(50),
 @NewDateIssued datetime,
 @NewExpirationDate datetime,
 @LicenceNumber nvarchar(50),
 @DateIssued datetime,
 @ExpirationDate datetime,
 @StateIssuedLicenceNumber nvarchar(50),
 @StateIssuedDateIssued datetime,
 @StateIssuedExpirationDate datetime
 )
 as

 Declare @CDateIssued datetime;
 Declare @CExpirationDate datetime; 
 Declare @CStateIssuedDateIssued datetime;
 Declare @CStateIssuedExpirationDate datetime;

 Set @CDateIssued= CONVERT(char(10),@DateIssued, 126);
 Set @CExpirationDate= CONVERT(char(10), @CExpirationDate, 126);
 Set @CStateIssuedDateIssued= CONVERT(char(10), @StateIssuedDateIssued, 126);
 Set @CStateIssuedExpirationDate= CONVERT(char(10), @StateIssuedExpirationDate, 126);

  UPDATE  [tbCompanyAgent]
  SET 
  LicenceNumber = @NewLicenceNumber,
  LicenceIssueDate = @NewDateIssued,
  LicenceExpirationDate =@NewExpirationDate
  WHERE
  LicenceNumber in (select distinct LicenceNumber 
  from tbLicence where LicenceNumber= @LicenceNumber AND          StateIssuedLicenseNumber= @StateIssuedLicenceNumber
  AND LicenceIssueDate = @CDateIssued AND StateIssuedLicenseIssuedDate =    @CStateIssuedDateIssued AND 
 StateIssuedLicenseExpirationDate = @CStateIssuedExpirationDate)
```

It is not updating information in tbCompanyAgent.
Please help me!!!

Comment: Create another table and let both tables refer these common columns from there on the basis of an ID. **IF** normalization is not an issue and your data is less than 10 million rows or something.

Comment: I cannot do it because It will take me ages to do it because of complex nature of business requirement...

Answer (score 0):

**First execute below query and see if you are getting any record or not. If you are getting record please verify it once.**

```
SELECT L.LicenceNumber, L.LicenceIssueDate, L.LicenceExpirationDate
FROM [tbCompanyAgent] CA
INNER JOIN tbLicence L on CA.LicenceNumber = L.LicenceNumber
WHERE L.LicenceNumber  = @LicenceNumber
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseNumber = @StateIssuedLicenceNumber
AND L.LicenceIssueDate = @CDateIssued
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseIssuedDate = @CStateIssuedDateIssued
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseExpirationDate = @CStateIssuedExpirationDate
```

If above query is giving you desired result, which you want to update in other table the just remove select statement and use update statement like this.

```
UPDATE CA
SET CA.LicenceNumber = L.LicenceNumber, CA.LicenceIssueDate = L.LicenceIssueDate, 
 CA.LicenceExpirationDate = L.LicenceExpirationDate
FROM [tbCompanyAgent] CA
INNER JOIN tbLicence L on CA.LicenceNumber = L.LicenceNumber
WHERE L.LicenceNumber  = @LicenceNumber
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseNumber = @StateIssuedLicenceNumber
AND L.LicenceIssueDate = @CDateIssued
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseIssuedDate = @CStateIssuedDateIssued
AND L.StateIssuedLicenseExpirationDate = @CStateIssuedExpirationDate
```

Comment: No first one is just for testing so that you can make sure whatever you are trying to achieve you are getting that. Once you sure just use the update query in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should include what table is the column you want to change so that the program will accurately know what it should update? e.g. tbLicence.LicenceNumber